# visual basic 6 access 2007 database programming cascading combo boxes

Tags: vb6, combobox, ms-access-2007, database-programming

I have a table named: `schoolInfo` in access 2007 and it has two fields `(schName and mjrName)`.

Now I'm trying to design a combo in Visual Basic 6 `(cboMajors)` which is related to the other combo `(cboSchool)`.

As a matter of fact I want to have to cascading combo boxes. When I choose an Item in cboSchool the other combo should represents just the related majors for that school `(records with schName=x and mjrName=y)`.

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()

connection
' the Connection is a code in module contains codes are needed to make the connection between form and the database

fill_schools
fill_majors

End Sub
```

Also,

```
Private Sub fill_schools()
 With rs

    .Open "select DISTINCT schName from tblSchoolsInfo", cn, 2, 3

        Do While Not .EOF
        cboSchool.AddItem (.Fields(0))
        .MoveNext
    Loop
  End With
  rs.Close
End Sub

Private Sub fill_majors()

 With rs
    .Open "select DISTINCT mjrName from tblSchoolsInfo where schName= '" & Me.cboSchool & " '", cn, 2, 3

        Do While Not .EOF
        cboMajors.AddItem (.Fields(0))
        .MoveNext
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Now: the first combo get correct values but the second one is completely empty.

Answer (score 1):

In the snippet of code you have given us, I can't see anywhere where you actually select the school in Form_Activate(). This means that by the end of that procedure, there will be no selection in school, so fill_majors() will execute:

```
select DISTINCT mjrName from tblSchoolsInfo where schName= ' '
```

Incidentally, is that trailing space deliberate? In which case, this won't return records even if a school is selected.

Comment: it's the Connection procedure duty to make the needed connections, I have a module like this:
'Public cn As New ADODB.connection
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Sub connection()
Set cn = New ADODB.connection
With cn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\sch.accdb; Persist Security Info=False"
    .Open
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
End With

End Sub'

Answer (score 1):

The OP solved this in dreamincode.net.  He was tacking an extra space on the end of his combo box string: Me.cboSchool & " '"

I've always wanted to say this: "This behavior is by design."  :)

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion did you check the 
cboMajors.AddItem (.Fields(0))  <--- .Fields()